# Why are so many bed surfaces black? Would white help?

Tags: heated-bed, build-plate

It occurred to me after recalling cooling problems in the layers near the bed that many popular build surfaces (e.g. BuildTak clones) are black, which should radiate the most heat - onto the part being printed, which is generally undesirable. Is there a reason for this? Are there (white) build surfaces designed to minimize radiation of heat that might help avoid cooling problems in the initial layers?

Comment: I suspect the difference would be negligible, but now I want a white one, just because it would be easier to see the print for most colors (except white, obviously)

Comment: I think black surfaces absorb and retain heat better but this is just knowledge from high school days.

Comment: My bed is blue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the color is just a design choice, and doesn't have that big of an effect on the print itself. Changing the color wouldn't have an effect on the print itself. If you are looking for a solution to minimize radiation of heat going up to the build, you could either lower the heat of the bed, or you could go into the advanced print settings and change the bed temp after the first couple layers.